# Detect AJAX requests in the browser (client side)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a way to detect via JavaScript (client side) any AJAX requests that are occurring and even get the number of requests in progress?

The reason I ask: I have a global processing indicator in an application being worked on with several developers, some of whom neglect to start and stop the indicator when making AJAX requests.

Is there a way to detect this?

I know the best way to handle it would be to trigger something with the requests and when the requests complete, but I can't control the other developers or rewrite legacy code, so I'm looking for something I can inject in with JavaScript to detect requests.

Comment: Buy a big club and beat your developers with it when they neglect to start and stop the indicator. Use version control to make sure you are beating up the right person.

Comment: @Kristopher: Are you using a framework? if not, how do you handle the XHR object?

Comment: @CMS: Yes, I'm using jQuery. Sorry for not specifying that.

Comment: will it always be jquery? every time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() { /* start indicator */ });

$(document).ajaxStop(function() { /* stop indicator */ });
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this *without* jQuery?

Comment: Are you using any library at all? If not, have a common function call to do your ajax requests and start/stop the indicator there. That's really what jQuery's ajaxStart + ajaxStop are doing if you look at the jQuery source.